# How early does New Orleans start filling up with Mardi Gras tourists?

Tags: event-based-effects, carnival-mardi-gras, new-orleans

The next Mardi Gras falls on 25 February 2020. I was hoping to visit New Orleans the week before (16-21 Feb). Can I get in and out of the city, find hotels, etc., without getting caught in the Mardi Gras madness (crowds, tourist pricing, hotel shortage, etc.)? Or is that too close to the holiday, and I should find another time to go?

## Update

To address the concern raised below in the comments, I will now rephrase my question: *How early does New Orleans start filling up with Mardi Gras tourists?*

Comment: How can this be other than opinion-based? One person's "too close" is another person's "just about right." I voted to close.

Comment: @David Rephrased question to address your concern.

Comment: By now, Mardi Gras madness goes on mostly all year.

Comment: @crmdgn I'm sorry, I still disagree: one person's "starts filling up" is another's "too full" or another's "there's still room." This isn't a good Stack Exchange question. Take a look at the "Don't Ask" page within the Help file: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Why not book the hotels now to be safe?

Comment: @crmdgn Try looking at package trips around your dates - it might throw up a jump in prices that will help inform what you want to know. Or talk to a knowledgeable travel agent?